# Implementing graphics for windows-phone silverlight game

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to implement a Snakes & Ladders board game for windows phone (8 or 8.1). There will be the classic snakes and ladders board map, but the graphics might need to change (frozen ladders if it is snowing outside, muddy spots on some of the tiles if it is raining etc)

I need a **simple** and easy way which will allow me to visualize the player moving through the tiles and ladders graphics etc changing. I have seen that in XAML grid if I set an image as background and then add controls in the grid (eg a button for each tile so I can visualize the player moving on each tile), the background image  gets overwritten.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this via having a button represent the Player and changing the button's **margin** to move it through the board (represented by a background image). Was not a clean way but the job got done pretty well.

As for the board-graphics changing, i just had 4 different images with the board state and loaded which one i needed in each case. Also not clean, but again got the job done.